# Swift: How to make viewWillTransition only effect iphones in landscape

Tags: ios, swift

I have been trying to make it so that view will transition will only return something if the device is an iphone in landscape mode using the following code:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
 super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(nil, completion: {
    _ in

    return x
})
}
```

I cant see how to make this code only execute if the device is an iphone in landscape mode or is there is a different way to do it.

Comment: you can accept an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Within your function, you can check the device idiom simply by using [Apple's provided UIKit APIs (under UIDevice)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiuserinterfaceidiom/1620049-phone).

```
let isPhone: Bool = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
```

Further more, using this same UIDevice API from UIKit, you can check the [orientation of the device](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidevice).

```
let isLandscape: Bool = UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape
```

For your example, you could do the following:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    if isPhone && isLandscape {
        coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(nil, completion: { _ in

        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check if it is an iPhone this way:

```
let isPhone: Bool = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
```

And you can get the screen orientation using this:

```
let isLandscape: Bool = UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape
```

So to do something only if it's a phone in landscape mode:

```
if isPhone && isLandscape {

}
```